# Master-Detail Datatable where master table it's a database view on gvNIX

Tags: java, datatables, spring-roo, gvnix

I'm looking for create a Master-Detail view on gvNIX where the master it's a view and the detail it's my own table loaded from my Oracle database, gvNIX has mapped the table on the dbre.xml in my project.gvNIX supports the creating of a master view Datatable? 
I use the reverse engineering command as it follows to create all models and controllers for all database tables

```
database reverse engineer --schema XXXX --package ~.domain
```

Thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-app#create-patterns-and-details-using-datatables

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not really, my question it's if gvNIX supports the creation of a Master-Detail view where the master table source it's requested from a database view and the detail table source it's requested from a database table
Thanks.

Comment: All in gvNIX and Roo are Entity oriented, so create an entity (dbre could do it for you) that maps to needed db view.